# How do I have an Angular.dart filtered list update automatically

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an html template that filters a list by the column property of the objects of that list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li card-view 
        card-id="state.card" 
        ng-repeat="state in ctrl.game.states | filter:{column:'backlog'} " 
        ng-include="cardview.html">
     </li>
</ul>
```

If I modify the column property in one of the elements of that list, the display does not update.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option that uses an imaginary placeholder tag and avoids the |filter replacing it with an ng-if, but I hope someone has a better answer than this one.

```
<ul>
    <xx ng-repeat="state in ctrl.game.states">
      <li card-view 
          card-id="state.card" 
          ng-if="state.column == 'backlog'" 
          ng-include="cardview.html">
       </li>
     </xx>
</ul>
```

Doing the ng-if and ng-repeat on the same element didn't work.

Comment: The performance of this solution is poor.  I've instead started manually filtering and updating a secondary list and using that in a normal ng-repeat.  I still hope someone else has a better solution.